# c++ dynamecly fill 2d vector when there is unknown rows or columns

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array, stdvector

i try to understand how can i hold dynamically 2d vector array ( or it can be other container  in c++ )
that i can fill dynameclly when i dont know the row nuber and the column number in each raw
what i have now is something like this but as you can see i have to define ahead the number of raws and columns

```
 std::vector<std::vector<BaseColumn*>> csv(1, std::vector<BaseColumn*> (1));
    std::string test = "d";
    Column<std::string>* tmpString = new Column<std::string>(Types::string,test);
    csv[0].push_back(tmpString);   
    csv[0].push_back(tmpString);
    csv[0].push_back(tmpString);
    csv[1].push_back(tmpString); //<--- Here im getting Segmentation fault
    csv[1].push_back(tmpString); 
    csv[1].push_back(tmpString); 
    csv[1].push_back(tmpString); 


Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ff655703f1a in std::__new_allocator<BaseColumn*>::construct<BaseColumn*, BaseColumn*> (this=0x1af24052af8, __p=0xabababababababab) at C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/new_allocator.h:175
175     { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

My question is simple how to construct 2d dynaic container ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::vector<...> csv(1, ...);
```

Here you say that the vector have only ***one*** element. That means any index that is not equal to `0` will be out of bounds.

You probably want

```
std::vector<...> csv(2);  // Let the nested vectors be default-initialized and *empty*
```

---

If you don't know the size of the vector, at compile-time *or* at run-time (for example you read rows from a file of an unknown size) then just push back the inner vectors as you read the rows from the file:

```
std::vector<std::vector<BaseColumn*>> csv;  // Create an empty vector

std::string input_line;
while (std::getline(input_file_stream, input_line))
{
    std::vector<BaseColumn*> one_row = parse_line_into_columns(input_line);
    csv.push_back(one_row);  // Add the row
}
```

Comment: no i just gave example , i have no idea how many row and each row how many col's 
i need it to be fully dynamic

Comment: @user63898 Then do you have the real number of rows in a variable? You can use that variable instead of the literal number. Or create an empty (outer) vector and push back the inner vectors.

Comment: so if i do 2d vector i loss the dynamic of vector ? i dont want to use nor fixed or predefined numbers

Comment: @user63898 You know about `push_back` to dynamically add elements to a vector. You can do it with any vector, no matter the element type (as long as it's either copyable or movable). Added very simple example to my answer.